# ASP.net MVC 4 Cloud

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, cloud

I know it is very broad question. But what things I have to take in to account when I write a new application in ASP .NET MVC  + SQL server  that would **run in Cloud**. Can I  still cloud based  and not use the Microsoft Azure technology?

Comment: FYI: I am planing to build an application  in MVC5 with spring

Comment: technically you can use any cloud to create a windows VM , install all the prerequisites and deploy your web application there.